# Several layouts in one xml layout - doesn't append text after button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was searching solution for my problem, but I didn't find any.

I'm creating android application and one activity layout has several activities:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".EkranGlowny"
android:id="@+id/aaa"
android:background="#ffff8000"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="540dp"
    android:background="#ffff8000"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Krystian Pruchnik"
        android:id="@+id/waiter_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID: 180881"
        android:id="@+id/waiter_id"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zamówienie"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/viewOrder"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="540dp"
    android:background="#69ff8300"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="@string/clear_button"
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="540dp"
    android:background="#69ff8300"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ScrollView
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:background="#ffff8000">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Zestawy"
                    android:id="@+id/zestawy"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:layout_span="3"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip">

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa1"
                    android:id="@+id/meal1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa2"
                    android:id="@+id/meal2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa3"
                    android:id="@+id/meal3"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa4"
                    android:id="@+id/meal4"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa5"
                    android:id="@+id/meal5"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa6"
                    android:id="@+id/meal6"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa7"
                    android:id="@+id/meal7"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa8"
                    android:id="@+id/meal8"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa9"
                    android:id="@+id/meal9"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa10"
                    android:id="@+id/meal10"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa11"
                    android:id="@+id/meal11"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa12"
                    android:id="@+id/meal12"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip" >

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa13"
                    android:id="@+id/meal13"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/potrawa14"
                    android:id="@+id/meal14"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#69ff8300"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:text="VOID"
            android:id="@+id/anuluj"
            android:background="#ffff2800" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rozlicz"
            android:id="@+id/rozlicz"
            android:layout_weight="1.18" />
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

I want that if I click some button (from second and third linear layout) it'll put text in TextView (id: viewOrder in first linear layout). Whenever I try this, it's showing message: "Unfortunately WaiterApp is stopped" and application crashes.

My Main Activity in java:

```
public class EkranGlowny extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

Button summary;
Context context;
Button but0;
Button but1;
Button but2;
Button but3;
Button but4;
Button but5;
Button but6;
Button but7;
Button but8;
Button but9;
Button butClr;
Button voiD;
Button meal1;
Button meal2;
Button meal3;
Button meal4;
Button meal5;
Button meal6;
Button meal7;
Button meal8;
Button meal9;
Button meal10;
Button meal11;
Button meal12;
Button meal13;
Button meal14;
TextView viewOrder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ekran_glowny);
    setupVariables();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.rozlicz:
            context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResumeScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        /*case R.id.button0:
            viewOrder.append(but0.getText().toString());
            break;

        case R.id.button1:
            viewOrder.append("1");
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            viewOrder.append("2");
            break;*/

        default:
            viewOrder.append(((Button) v).getText().toString());
            break;
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//implementacja zmiennych
private void setupVariables() {
    summary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rozlicz);
    summary.setOnClickListener(this);
    but0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    but0.setOnClickListener(this);
    but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    but1.setOnClickListener(this);
    but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    but2.setOnClickListener(this);
    but3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    but3.setOnClickListener(this);
    but4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    but4.setOnClickListener(this);
    but5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    but5.setOnClickListener(this);
    but6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    but6.setOnClickListener(this);
    but7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    but7.setOnClickListener(this);
    but8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    but8.setOnClickListener(this);
    but9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    but9.setOnClickListener(this);
    butClr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_button);
    butClr.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal1);
    meal1.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal2);
    meal2.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal3);
    meal3.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal4);
    meal4.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal5);
    meal5.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal6);
    meal6.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal7);
    meal7.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal8);
    meal8.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal9);
    meal9.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal10);
    meal10.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal11);
    meal11.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal12);
    meal12.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal13);
    meal13.setOnClickListener(this);
    meal14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meal14);
    meal14.setOnClickListener(this);
    voiD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anuluj);
    voiD.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewOrder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewOrder);
}
```

}

I tried viewOrder.setText and viewOrder.append and nothing is working.
Is the problem is that TextView and buttons are in different layouts?
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

edit:

In logcat I get:
06-07 14:17:40.290    7755-7755/com.example.krystian.waiterapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40da51f8)
06-07 14:17:40.290    7755-7755/com.example.krystian.waiterapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.krystian.waiterapp.EkranGlowny.onClick(EkranGlowny.java:78)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is the error message that you get in your logcat?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.krystian.waiterapp.EkranGlowny.onClick(EkranGlowny.java:79)

Comment: Is that your full exception message? There should be more.

Comment: I added full message in first post at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your xml file name. It should be `ekran_glowny`.

My guess is you showed xml code from different xml file.

Comment: It's correct.  The first case when i call new activity is working after clicking button

Comment: @p3sman your code works fine [Activity](http://pastebin.com/8VE07DYu) [Layout](http://pastebin.com/48M8eaXw) also ActionBarActivity is deprecated. Use AppCompatActivity instead.

Comment: So why it didn't work for me? changing ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity wil cause my code working?

Comment: @p3sman are you sure you provided correct codes and entire logcat error  message? check code from my previous comment.

Comment: I'm sure. I check your code too. Still the same error. I updated logcat in my post but it's not really different

Comment: @p3sman code works. try recreate / rename layout xml file. it may be layout with same name in layout folder for different orientation etc.

Comment: What if I tell you that I have several layouts for different screen dpi? I have ekran_glowny.xml in layout, layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi. Is this relevant?

Comment: @p3sman check you have textview with id `viewOrder` in each layout

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. In layouts for mdpi and hdpi was no id for TextView. Now everything works as I want.